# GIT: Centralized Workflow simple question

Tags: git, gitlab, cgi-bin

I am new to GIT. I am using Centralized Workflow like SVN.

GIT works great for DEV(local repository) to PROD(remote repository) structure.

Now, we hired a QA/tester. QA/Tester must approve dev changes before remote pushing to PROD.

Question: How would QA/Tester get DEV's repository to test?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are many different git workflows that will solve your problem. Too many to list here.

The simplest answer is that you should use branches. Develop your code on a branch named `develop` (in both your local and remote repositories), and have the tester merge that branch into `master` periodically when it passes testing.

You should read about some different git workflows and decide which would suit you best:

- [Trunk Based Development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/)
- [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)
- [Centralized](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#centralized-workflow)
- [Feature Branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow)